# Encoding issue in XML feed

Tags: php, xml, feed, utf

I am trying to generate XML feed in php, for outsourcing.
But because of some single dirty entry in the data coming from database, I am getting following error.

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 11 at column 44: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0x01 0x20 0x50 0x65
error on line 11 at column 44: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction fixing this issue?

**EDIT**

I am generating the feed as following:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
<source>
    <item>
        <description><![CDATA[<?=$desc?>]]></description>
    </item>
</source>
```

Comment: Perhaps, if you show how you are generating those feeds in PHP. The error is only the symptom - the disease is the code.

Comment: I have added the code in the edit section.

Comment: You need to know the encoding that your application is supposed to use, configure your DB class to declare such encoding and finally convert text from such input encoding to UTF-8. If you don't know what I'm talking about, you should consider just switching to UTF-8 everywhere—that way you won't need to do anything.

Comment: Please read _[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)_, it'll help save your day and your future. It's an easy read, time well spent.